# Jones Polynomial of disjoints link using skein relation

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I'm reading the very detail course of Neil Strickland.

In proposition 7.14 Page 22.

[Strickland course  KNOTS AND SURFACES](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/MAS344/MAS344.pdf)

I would like to prove this proposition using  the Jones Polynomial of disjoints link.

ie

Find $V(K_1 \sqcup K_2)$ using Skein relation.

For that,I  set: 
$ L_-=L_+=K_1\#K_2$ and $L_0=K_1 \sqcup K_2$.
 
I'm trouble to see when the relation $ L_-=L_+=K_1\#K_2$  hold.

Comment: Hi, the link can not be found.

Comment: Here is the link https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/MAS344/